# ¿Cómo lleno un arreglo con distintos tipos de elementos con interfaz?

Tags: java, interfaz

Estoy elaborando un sistema de créditos. Su función es completar los datos, presionar el botón CALCULAR y recopilar el valor de créditos en la parte derecha por medio de una lista.

Mi inquietud es cómo codificar un arreglo que me permita almacenar todos los campos de texto (nombre, cedula, valor, interés, cuotas) con el fin de que al presionar el botón GUARDAR, éste se almacene en un arreglo para posterior, presionar el botón BUSCAR, introducir con un JOptionPane la cedula y se imprima en los campos de texto los datos introducidos anteriormente.

[image]

Comment: una idea es hacer uso de POO puedes convertir esos datos en un objeto y almacenarlos en un array de objetos ,al cual puedes acceder mediante getters

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola!.

Yo crearía una clase con todos los campos a almacenar, por ejemplo:

```
public class Datos{

   private String nombre;
   private String cedula;
   private double valor;

   public Datos(String nombre, String cedula, double valor){

       this.nombre = nombre;
       this.cedula = cedula;
       this.valor = valor;
   }
}
```

Luego crearía la instancia:

```
Datos datos1 = new Datos(nombre, cedula, valor);
```

Pero no construiría un arreglo, usaría un ArrayList, el cual debería importar con

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

... para almacenar la clase Datos en una clase aparte llamada, por ejemplo GuardarDatos.java. Eso sería más simple y potente y me permitiría hacer el resto sin problemas. Lo cual se podría hacer de una forma parecida a esta:

```
ArrayList guardarDatos = new ArrayList();
guardarDatos.add(datos1);
```

¡Y eso es todo!.